# Google maps transit_station also shows bus stations

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to display all METRO STOPS and TRAM STOPS on a map. I'm doing so via [the Radar Search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests). It gives back all locations matching a *type* within a given radius. [These types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) are possible.

So I'm basically doing a search on the types `subway_station` for metro and `transit_station` for tram stops.

The problem is that `transit_station` also returns bus stations (which also has its separate type `bus_station` so I would expect them not to be returned via the `transit_station` type).

This is the URL I'm making the request to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?type=transit_station&location=51.055154,3.726752&radius=5000&key=[MY_API_KEY]
```

So I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or my request is simply not possible via Google Maps?

Comment: please put your code so i understand better . in which lat long you face this  problem ?

Comment: first you also check there is only issue in your city or other city also ? just put other city lat long and check it .

Comment: @HarshilKotecha I have checked it for 2 cities: Ghent, Belgium and Brussels, Belgium. Both display bus stations as well. There isn't much code I can show, as I'm just making a request to the API url. I've changed my question to include that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that `transit_station` is a generic type that includes `train_station`, `bus_station`, `subway_station` and `light_rail_station`.

I think you should use a separate `light_rail_station` type for trams:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.055154%2C3.726752&radius=5000&type=light_rail_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Also, I figured out that many stations are marked as a bus_station and light_rail_station at the same time.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the answer! I didn't know about light_rail_station because it isn't documented. Is the screenshot you included coming from Google Maps or is this your own app?

Comment: This is my app, I just show fields from web service response. Indeed the light_rail_station is not documented, I think you should file a documentation bug in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188872).